# Replace TCustomEdit context menu with my own

Tags: windows, delphi

I want to replace all the popup menus displayed by delphi in the TCustomEdit components like TEdit or TMemo using my own popup menu (which has a lot of more actions). So far I replace the PopUpMenu property of each component manually with my own TPopUpMenu. but I wondering if I can do this without modify this property manually for each component in all my forms.

I want something like a hook to intercept the calls to this system menu and replace for my own menu. is this possible?

[image]

Comment: Why not just subclass TEdit and TMemo and have them share a context menu?

Comment: If you showed how to do that, @Warren, I expect it would fall within the realm of acceptable answers to this question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In your main form, add the following code.  It should apply to all your form's custom control.

```
TForm2 = class(TForm)
  procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
private
  procedure ActiveControlChanged(Sender: TObject);
end;

implementation

type
  TCustomEditAccess = class(TCustomEdit);
  TCustomGridAccess = class(TCustomGrid);

procedure TForm2.ActiveControlChanged(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if (Screen.ActiveControl is TCustomEdit) and not Assigned(TCustomEditAccess(Screen.ActiveControl).PopupMenu) then
    TCustomEditAccess(Screen.ActiveControl).PopupMenu := MyPopupMenu
  else if (Screen.ActiveControl is TCustomGrid) then
  begin
    TCustomGridAccess(Screen.ActiveControl).ShowEditor;
    if Assigned(TCustomGridAccess(Screen.ActiveControl).InplaceEditor) then
      TCustomEditAccess(TCustomGridAccess(Screen.ActiveControl).InplaceEditor).PopupMenu := MyPopupMenu;
  end;
end;

procedure TForm2.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Screen.OnActiveControlChange := ActiveControlChanged;
end;
```

It is just a simplified version (in the point of view of coding) of kobik's answer and will also address any TCustomEdit that are created by code or other complex Controls which do not use the Form as Owner.

His instruction on how to determine which CustomEdit popup apply.

Edit : Add Grid InplaceEditor Support

Comment: As I mentioned in my answer `OnActiveControlChange` fires too late (*after* the context menu is poped-up), if you right-click on a `TEdit` without first setting it as the active control (you can test it by putting a number of TEdits on your form).

Comment: I have tested them and they worked very well.... I can directly right click those edit without caption and it popup my menu. Do it differ between version?

Comment: @kobik  I add much more edits, using code to create TEdit using Panel as owner, adding stringgrid, I also create other forms then the main form and add edits.  They all show up my own menu no matter the control is focused or not when I right-click them. I cannot simulate a case with the original menu popup.

Comment: `OnActiveControlChange` was my initial thought. I have tested in D5. if `Edit1` is focused and I right-click on `Edit2`, it will first pop-up the default menu, only then it becomes the active control. so this might differ between versions.

Comment: @kobik I am using Delphi 2010 and it definitely work.  So, I think your way is more version friendly.  I would suggest to change the search to a parent.FindChildControl self-calling loop to find also the components not owned by the form though.  Also, CustomEdit created after the form get focus will not be set.

Comment: OK, I finally tested this with D7 and D2009. both works just fine, so It's a D5 issue :/ Surely this solution is better than mine.

Answer (score 6):

If your Forms derives from a common ancestor (rather than the default `TForm`) for example `TMyBaseForm`, meaning `TForm1 = class(TMyBaseForm)` this could be done easy. 
In the `TMyBaseForm.OnShow` event you could iterate through it's controls, and if you find a `TEdit` or `TMemo` you set their `PopupMenu` property dynamically.

Another way is to use `Screen.OnActiveFormChange` (`Screen.OnActiveControlChange` fires too late if you right-click on the active  control - **EDIT: This is True only with D5**) in your main Form event handler to capture the active form and iterate through the `Screen.ActiveForm` controls and set `TEdit` or `TMemo` property `PopupMenu` to your custom `MyPopupMenu`:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  Screen.OnActiveFormChange := ActiveFormChange;
end;    

procedure TForm1.ActiveFormChange(Sender: TObject);
begin
  CustomEditControlsNormalize(Screen.ActiveForm);
end;

type
  TCustomEditAccess = class(TCustomEdit);

procedure TForm1.CustomEditControlsNormalize(F: TForm);
var
  I: Integer;
begin
  if not Assigned(F) then Exit;
  for I := 0 to F.ComponentCount - 1 do
    if F.Components[I] is TCustomEdit then
      TCustomEditAccess(F.Components[I]).Popupmenu := MyPopupMenu;
end;
```

---

To determine which `TCustomEdit` control caused the Popupmenu to pop-up refer to the `MyPopupMenu.PopupComponent` (in the `MyPopupMenu.OnPopup` event):

```
procedure TForm1.MyPopupMenuPopup(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if MyPopupMenu.PopupComponent is TCustomEdit then
  begin
    FEditPopupControl := TCustomEdit(MyPopupMenu.PopupComponent);
    Caption := FEditPopupControl.Name; // debug :-P
  end;
end;
```

---

**EDIT:** `Screen.OnActiveControlChange` was my initial thought. I have tested it in D5. if Edit1 is focused and I right-click on Edit2, it will first pop-up the default menu, only then it becomes the active control. 
I finally tested this with D7 and D2009. both works just fine. This is a **D5 issue only** so [Justmade's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9687324/937125) is surely a better solution than using `Screen.OnActiveFormChange`.

Answer (score 5):

You could assign a single `OnContextPopup` event handler to all of the edit controls, have it call the `Popup()` method of the `TPopupMenu`, and set the event's `Handled` parameter to `True`.  But that is not much different than just assigning the `TPopupMenu` to all of the edit controls directly.

To take it a step further, you could assign a single `OnContextPopup` event handler to your parent `TForm` instead of the individual edit controls.  The event tells you the mouse coordinates when the menu is being invoked by mouse.  You can locate the child control underneath those coordinates, and if it is one of your edit conrols then call `Popup()` and set `Handled` to True.  The user can invoke menus by keyboard instead, in which case the mouse coordinates will be `{-1, -1}`, so use the `TScreen.ActiveControl` property to know which control is being invoked on.

Answer (score 2):

You can do the Popup assignment directly on a installed hook in the TEdit or TMemo Class' `NewInstance` method. With this tecnique you'll only have to include an additional unit with installs the hook. The hook's code will assign your custom TPopupMenu object to the `PopupMenu` property  of every component of class `TEdit` and `TMemo` created in your application.

First, drop a TPopupMenu object in a global TDatamodule or your main Form. The key point here, is that the PopupMenu parent should always be available and be the first one created at your application initialization, or at least before the hook is installed.

Then, create a empty new unit. Call it whatever you want. In my case `popup_assignment.pas`. The source is this:

```
unit popup_assignment;

interface

uses Windows, StdCtrls;


implementation

uses globaldatamodule; // Unit of global TPopupMenu parent

{------------------------------------------------------------------------------}

function TEditNewInstance(AClass: TClass): TObject;
begin
    Result := TEdit.NewInstance;
    TEdit(Result).PopupMenu := global_datamodule.customedit_popupmenu; // <- your global TPopupMenu component !!!
end;

function TMemoNewInstance(AClass: TClass): TObject;
begin
    Result := TMemo.NewInstance;
    TMemo(Result).PopupMenu := global_datamodule.customedit_popupmenu; // <- your global TPopupMenu component !!!
end;

function GetVirtualMethod(AClass: TClass; const VmtOffset: Integer): Pointer;
begin
    Result := PPointer(Integer(AClass) + VmtOffset)^;
end;

procedure SetVirtualMethod(AClass: TClass; const VmtOffset: Integer; const Method: Pointer);
var
    WrittenBytes: DWORD;
    PatchAddress: PPointer;
begin
    PatchAddress := Pointer(Integer(AClass) + VmtOffset);
    WriteProcessMemory(GetCurrentProcess, PatchAddress, @Method, SizeOf(Method), WrittenBytes);
end;


{$IFOPT W+}{$DEFINE WARN}{$ENDIF}{$WARNINGS OFF} // no compiler warning
const
    vmtNewInstance = System.vmtNewInstance;
{$IFDEF WARN}{$WARNINGS ON}{$ENDIF}

var
    orgTEditNewInstance: Pointer;
    orgTMemoNewInstance: Pointer;

initialization
    orgTEditNewInstance := GetVirtualMethod(TEdit, vmtNewInstance);
    orgTMemoNewInstance := GetVirtualMethod(TMemo, vmtNewInstance);

    SetVirtualMethod(TEdit, vmtNewInstance, @TEditNewInstance);
    SetVirtualMethod(TMemo, vmtNewInstance, @TMemoNewInstance);

finalization
    SetVirtualMethod(TEdit, vmtNewInstance, OrgTEditNewInstance);
    SetVirtualMethod(TMemo, vmtNewInstance, orgTMemoNewInstance);

end.
```

Comment: The unit code creates a hook for every TEdit or TMemo object in your app. You may add more classes easily.

Answer (score 2):

Add a TApplicationEvents component to your delphi application.
Make your own popupmenu (popupmenu1)?
In the OnMessage of the TApplicationEvents component add the following code:

```
procedure TForm1.ApplicationEvents1Message(var Msg: tagMSG; var Handled: Boolean);
var
  ctrl: TWincontrol;

begin
  if (msg.Message = WM_RBUTTONUP) or (msg.Message = WM_KEYUP ) then begin
     ctrl := FindControl(Msg.hwnd);
     if ctrl <> nil then begin
       if ((ctrl is TEdit))  then begin
        (ctrl as TEdit).PopupMenu := Popupmenu1;
       end;
       if ((ctrl is TMemo))  then begin
        (ctrl as TMemo).PopupMenu := Popupmenu1;
       end;
     end;
   end;
end;
```

This will intercept rightclick and if at that time there is a TEdit or TMemo under your mousecursor it will link popupmenu to that component and fire it.

Comment: Better will be to use message constants than a magical numbers `517 = 0x205 = WM_RBUTTONUP` and you may use `Ctrl := FindControl(Msg.hwnd);` instead of searching constrols by coordinates ;-)

Comment: Popup menu can be invoked by the keyboard also.

Comment: I implemented `Ctrl := FindControl(Msg.hwnd);` which also enabled to watch for WM_KEYUP, so now it also works when invoked from keyboard. I know it's dirty but there's no real clean way to do it without rebuilding your application from the ground up.

Comment: For this purpose is specifically intended the `WM_CONTEXTMENU` message. Unfortunately this event is not generated when user clicks the right mouse button (what you have already covered by `WM_RBUTTONUP`) but still instead of `WM_KEYUP` I would use the `WM_CONTEXTMENU`. However I like this way and giving you my +1. And add the `begin` after the first line ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Other possibilities:

1. Use available experts functionalities:

   - Use CnPack Property Corrector and define action that prompt you on specified component drop.
   - Use GExperts Rename/Replace Components futures (required implementation of your custom controls)
2. Most complicated - implement TForm descendant witch [design time drag and drop](http://www.delphidabbler.com/tips/76) and modify dropped controls PupupMenu property.
3. Ugly but flexible and without any descendant controls implementation - use below procedure:

   - CustomizePopupMenu(Form, [TEdit, TMemo], MyPopupMenu)
   - CustomizePopupMenu(AnyForm, [TEdit, TMemo], AnyPopupMenu)

---

```
procedure CustomizePopupMenu(
  const aCtrl: TWinControl;
  const aClasses: array of TControlClass;
  const aPopUp: TPopupMenu);

  procedure Process(const aCtrl: TWinControl;
    const aClasses: array of TControlClass; const aPopUp: TPopupMenu);

    procedure Match(const aCtrl: TControl;
      const aClasses: array of TControlClass; const aPopUp: TPopupMenu);
    var
      Ix: Integer;
    begin
      for Ix := Low(aClasses) to High(aClasses) do
      begin
        if aCtrl.InheritsFrom(aClasses[Ix]) then
           aCtrl.PopupMenu:= aPopUp;
      end;
    end;

  var
    Ix: Integer;
    Ctrl: TControl;
  begin
    for Ix := 0 to Pred(aCtrl.ControlCount) do
    begin

      if aCtrl.Controls[Ix] is TWinControl then
         Process(TWinControl(aCtrl.Controls[Ix]), aClasses, aPopUp);
      Match(aCtrl.Controls[Ix], aClasses, aPopUp)

    end;
  end;


begin
  if (aCtrl <> nil) and (Length(aClasses) > 0) and (aPopUp <> nil) then
     Process(aCtrl, aClasses, aPopUp)
end;
```